# How do i get the most common value? It keeps on returning me integer

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and i'm trying to get the most visited airport. How do i get just the name of the most counted ?

I did some of the select count method but it kept returning me number instead of the name instead. 
Example

```
userID | ICAO
-------------
  1    |  KQTX
  4    |  KQTX
  3    |  KQTQ
  2    |  KQTX
  2    |  KQTQ
  1    |  KQTQ
  4    |  KQTX



$get = DB::get_row('SELECT `ICAO`,COUNT(`ICAO`) AS `totalicao` 
from table_icao 
GROUP BY `ICAO` 
ORDER BY `totalicao` DESC');

return $get->totalicao;
```

Once i did this, all it returned me was numbers. I want like the name of the ICAO itself like KQTQ.

Comment: `return $get->ICAO;`

Comment: You are only returning the count number?

Comment: Try `return $get;` and then output `echo $get->ICAO . ' - ' . $get->totalicao;`

Comment: Omg, return $get->ICAO; works!

Comment: Managed to display it guys! Thanks a lot. Is there a way for me to exclude?

Comment: Exclude what???

Comment: Just click the `delete` link below the question...

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want to exclude example KQTQ. Like let says KQTQ is the most popular because it is the home of the airport. Hence, i do not want KQTQ to be part of the most visited airport. Thus, i want to exclude it. I tried NOT IN ('KQTQ') but it gave me no data which i catch in my application

Comment: A WHERE clause like `WHERE ICAO != 'KQTQ'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yea i did it. Still could not get data

Answer (score 1):

You want the ICAO which occurs most often in the ICAO column, right?

Try this as your query:

```
'SELECT ICAO from table_icao GROUP BY ICAO ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1'
```

and then get the ICAO value from the row.

Comment: How do i exclude a name? I use NOT IN but it gives me no data

Comment: From the top of my head: `...from table_icao WHERE (ICAO != "KQTQ") GROUP BY...` - if != doesn't work, try NOT LIKE. NOT IN is for multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing the query so it returns one row:

```
SELECT `ICAO`, COUNT(`ICAO`) AS `totalicao` 
from table_icao 
GROUP BY `ICAO` 
ORDER BY `totalicao` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Then return the value from `ICAO` rather than `totalicao`.

Comment: Okay i managed to do it thanks to u_mulder. Is there anyway for me to exclude like example, KQTX?

Comment: @Syafiq . . . You can add a `where` clause to the query.

Comment: An example of how to put the where clause?

Comment: Its like example, KQTQ is a home town airport and i don't want to include KQTQ.

Comment: Put the WHERE before the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @ChrisWhite like this 
WHERE `ICAO` NOT IN ( 'KQTQ' ) ??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ICAO, COUNT(*) c FROM totalicao  GROUP BY ICAO ORDER BY c DESC limit 1
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked! Now, how can i exclude a certain ICAO ? Its like example, KQTQ is a home town airport and i don't want to include KQTQ but i want the next top icao to display